# Wrap multiple method calls (that each have different signatures) in a single handler

Tags: c#

I have multiple calls to methods in a 3rd party library.
These methods have a wide variety of different signatures / parameter combinations.

There are specific errors that the 3rd party library generates that I would like to catch and handle, and since the resolution is the same I would like it to take place in a single handler.

So I want to be able to have a method that essentially takes in as parameters a function (delegate) and its arguments, and invokes it inside some try/catch logic.

I don't know if its just not possible or I'm not getting the syntax right, but I can't figure out how to handle the fact that the signature for each method being passed in is different.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `Action` and `Func<T>` to wrap the methods, and closures to pass arguments.

```
public TResult CallMethod<TResult>(Func<ThirdPartyClass, TResult> func)
{
    try
    {
        return func(this.wrappedObject);
    }
    catch(ThirdPartyException e)
    {
        // Handle
    }
}

public void CallMethod(Action<ThirdPartyClass> method)
{
    this.CallMethod(() => { method(this.WrappedObject); return 0; });
}
```

You could then use this via:

```
var result = wrapper.CallMethod(thirdParty => thirdParty.Foo(bar, baz));
```

---

Edit: The above was assuming you were wrapping an instance of the third party library.  Given (from your comments) that these are static methods, you can just use:

```
public static TResult CallMethod<TResult>(Func<TResult> func)
{
    try
    {
        return func();
    }
    catch(ThirdPartyException e)
    {
        // Handle
    }
}

public static void CallMethod(Action method)
{
    CallMethod(() => { method(); return 0; });
}
```

And then call via:

```
var result = Wrapper.CallMethod(() => ThirdParty.Foo(bar, baz));
```

Comment: thanks. Where does WrappedObject come from - is this an instance of the 3rd party class?

I have a bit of a complication in that the 3rd party class is a static class, but I suppose I can create a non-static class to front it and expose the methods that way.

Comment: @bkr This was assuming your "wrapper" was wrapping an instance of the object.  Without that, it's actually easier - I'll edit and show

Comment: works like a charm (although had to remove the "this" from this.CallMethod on the static implementation.) now I need to sit down and understand what's actually going on here.

Comment: @brk Thanks for pointing that out - I fixed my call (was a copy/paste error).  Basically, you're passing the method to call as a delegate, and then having the wrapper call it for you.  This lets the wrapper handle the exceptions for any method you wish...

Comment: Not sure I understand this - this solution assumes that the parameter to the method call is always ThirdPartyClass - and the way I understood the question was that the parameters varied from method to method. Did I miss something here? Although the answer was accepted so I assume I missed something :-)

Comment: @GrahamHc The idea would be that you'd make your own method (probably via a lambda expression to make an anonymous method) that would do whatever you wanted using the ThirdPartyClass instance.  The methods could be anything - the reason I passed it in was so you had access to the object in question.